How does liftM2 work like the S' combinator in Haskell?
I was watching a video by code_report (Link) where he mentions liftM2 works like the S' combinator from combinatory logic. In his example he calculates the min/max element of an array and takes their gcd. Here's his solution.
solve = liftM2 gcd maximum minimum
While I can check and verify that this works, I can't for the love of god figure out how.
liftM2 gcd works just like I would expect. Given two lists it calculates the gcd for every possible pair. Easy. How then can I give it two functions [Int] -> Int and get out a single value. Not even a single value inside a list.
Can someone please explain and also go into how I could find this from just looking at the types. I consider myself pretty good at the basics of Haskell and thought I had grasped monads, even monadic functions like State but this is tripping me up.

Start by defining M a = [Int] -> a and treat M as a monad. liftM2 gcd can then take two values of type M Int and produce a value of type M Int. Work out the involved types and observe they check out. Then study the monad implementation (it's the reader monad under another name, essentially M = (->) [Int]) and compute liftM2 f x y applying the definitions at hand.

Thank you, I was so close, but what tripped me up was my assumption that [Int] -> Int would generalize to [a] -> a instead of r -> a. That's why I couldn't make up a monad instance that made any sense. I ended up reimplementing the (->) r monad and it all fell into place. Here's the official implementation for anyone still wondering.

@nessel Rollback your last edit, and make another answer out of it.

This is a good exercise in unification.
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
gcd :: Int -> Int -> Int
liftM2 gcd :: Monad m => m Int -> m Int -> m Int
minimum, maximum :: [Int] -> Int
m Int ~ [Int] -> Int ~ ((->) [Int]) Int
m ~ (->) [Int]
liftM2 gcd maximum minimum :: [Int] -> Int

Remember that the unification problem f a ~ g b decomposes as f ~ g and a ~ b, that [Int] -> Int is shorthand for (->) [Int] Int, and that function application associates to the left.

I figured it out!
The monad instance here has nothing to do with lists. It's (->) r, i.e. all functions that take the same input of type r and return some unspecified type. In the implementation for (>>=) you basically pass around the input reapplying it to every function. This only works because every function has the same type for the input argument.
In order for the monad instance to work, you first need to implement the Functor and the Applicative typeclass. You can do so by taking the general types for their functions and replacing every polymorphic f a with (r -> a). Finding the correct implementation at that point really is just a matter of correctly puzzling together the types.
One example:
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

-- for f = (->) r this becomes...
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)

-- You can then follow the types to find and implementation
fmap f g = \r -> f (g r)

-- Upon closer inspection, we can simplify: amazingly fmap is just composition...
fmap = (.)

To get back to the question, liftM2 lifts gcd into such a functional monad. Here r = [Int]. You could also implement it using do notation since we have a monad.
solve = do
  max <- maximum
  min <- minimum
  return $ gcd min max

Thanks to everyone who answered! This exploration really made my day.

With the :set -XTypeApplications language extension in ghci, you can instantiate the Applicative functor directly and it will infer the type of S: liftA2 @((->) _) :: (a -> b -> c) -> (_ -> a) -> (_ -> b) -> (_ -> c)

Nice, I assume that's the same as using language extensions directly in your source file. Though my problem here was finding the Applicative to begin with. In retrospect, :t liftM2 gcd minimum might've gotten me there.

For that you can write liftA2 @[] gcd maximum minimum using the incorrect Applicative and ghc will correct you.
